# Tkinter Collision and Dragging

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, collision-detection

I am trying to make a tkinter game where the player takes 'steps', (where each step has a start x & y, and an end x & y) and there are walls, which I have stored in an array with start and end points. I would like to make it so that when ever a player collides or crosses a wall, they are instead dragged along the wall and don't go through it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is just basic math. If the player's x or y coordinate is beyond the x/y coordinate of a wall, don't change the x/y coordinate of the player. Have you tried doing that?

Comment: but then how does the player get 'dragged along the wall' if the x and y coordinates are not changing? Thanks

Comment: It's just math. How do you define "dragged along"? If it's a vertical wall, do they slowly go up or down? Don't change the x coordinate, but slowly change the Y.

Comment: So if the wall was vertical, and I have the endpoints, would I find the slope of the wall and add that to the current x and current y as the new end point for the player? By dragged along I mean move but not through the wall.

Comment: sorry, I meant if the wall wasn't vertical.